# Error executing action `start` on resource 'supervisor_service[service-analytics_poller]'

Tags: azure, chef-infra, scalr

I'm trying to Integrate Azure public cloud with Scalr and made some configuration changes like adding Azure "app_client_id,  app_secret_key " in scalr-server.rb file. After saving this changes, i'm trying to run the reconfiguration command "sudo /opt/scalr-server/bin/scalr-server-ctl reconfigure" for reload/restart the services/components. But in doing so I ran into an error " Error executing action `start` on resource 'supervisor_service[service-analytics_poller]". So can any one from the other end help me out please.

Error Details :

```
    RuntimeError
    ------------
    Supervisor service service-analytics_poller was unable to be started

    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
    /opt/scalr-server/embedded/cookbooks/supervisor/providers/service.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in class_from_file'
    /opt/scalr-server/embedded/cookbooks/supervisor/providers/service.rb:47:in `block in class_from_file'

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /opt/scalr-server/embedded/cookbooks/scalr-server/recipes/group_service_always_post.rb

      5:   supervisor_service name do
      6:     command         "#{bin_dir_for node, 'service'}/scalrpy_proxy" \
      7:                     " #{run_dir_for node, 'service'}/#{svc[:name]}.pid" \
      8:                     " #{node[:scalr_server][:install_root]}/embedded/bin/python" \
      9:                     " #{scalr_bundle_path node}/app/python/scalrpy/#{svc[:service_module]}.py" \
     10:                     " --pid-file=#{run_dir_for node, 'service'}/#{svc[:name]}.pid" \
     11:                     " --log-file=#{log_dir_for node, 'service'}/python-#{svc[:name]}.log" \
     12:                     " --user=#{node[:scalr_server][:app][:user]}" \
     13:                     " --group=#{node[:scalr_server][:app][:user]}" \
     14:                     " --config=#{scalr_bundle_path node}/app/etc/config.yml" \
     15:                     ' --verbosity=INFO' \
     16:                     " #{svc[:service_extra_args]}" \
     17:                     # Note: 'start' is added by the proxy.
     18:     stdout_logfile  "#{log_dir_for node, 'supervisor'}/#{name}.log"
     19:     stderr_logfile  "#{log_dir_for node, 'supervisor'}/#{name}.err"
     20:     autostart       true
     21:     action          [:enable, :start]
     22:     subscribes      :restart, 'file[scalr_config]' if should_restart
     23:     subscribes      :restart, 'file[scalr_code]' if should_restart
     24:     subscribes      :restart, 'file[scalr_cryptokey]' if should_restart
     25:     subscribes      :restart, 'file[scalr_id]' if should_restart
     26:     subscribes      :restart, 'user[scalr_user]' if should_restart
     27:   end
     28: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /opt/scalr-server/embedded/cookbooks/scalr-server/recipes/group_service_always_post.rb:5:in `block in from_file'

    supervisor_service("service-analytics_poller") do
      action [:enable, :start]
      updated true
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :supervisor_service
      cookbook_name :"scalr-server"
      recipe_name "group_service_always_post"
      command "/opt/scalr-server/libexec/service/scalrpy_proxy /opt/scalr-server/var/run/service/analytics_poller.pid /opt/scalr-server/embedded/bin/python /opt/scalr-server/embedded/scalr/app/python/scalrpy/analytics_poller.py --pid-file=/opt/scalr-server/var/run/service/analytics_poller.pid --log-file=/opt/scalr-server/var/log/service/python-analytics_poller.log --user=scalr-app --group=scalr-app --config=/opt/scalr-server/embedded/scalr/app/etc/config.yml --verbosity=INFO "
      stdout_logfile "/opt/scalr-server/var/log/supervisor/service-analytics_poller.log"
      stderr_logfile "/opt/scalr-server/var/log/supervisor/service-analytics_poller.err"
      autostart true
      startsecs 1
      service_name "service-analytics_poller"
      process_name "%(program_name)s"
      numprocs 1
      numprocs_start 0
      priority 999
      autorestart :unexpected
      startretries 3
      exitcodes [0, 2]
      stopsignal :TERM
      stopwaitsecs 10
      stdout_logfile_maxbytes "50MB"
      stdout_logfile_backups 10
      stdout_capture_maxbytes "0"
      stderr_logfile_maxbytes "50MB"
      stderr_logfile_backups 10
      stderr_capture_maxbytes "0"
      serverurl "AUTO"
    end

Running handlers:
[2016-11-30T09:37:25-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
  - Raven::Chef::SentryHandler
Running handlers complete
[2016-11-30T09:37:26-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-11-30T09:37:26-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/scalr-server/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 53 resources updated in 10.841172558 seconds
[2016-11-30T09:37:26-05:00] ERROR: supervisor_service[service-analytics_poller] (scalr-server::group_service_always_post line 5) had an error: RuntimeError: Supervisor service service-analytics_poller was unable to be started
[2016-11-30T09:37:26-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: Check your service log (and not chef logs), there's probably something wrong in the configuration.

Comment: I have seen the service-analytics_poller.log, but haven't find any fix

Comment: This is the one I can see in that log file     [30/Nov/2016 14:37:25][    analytics_poller][ 13452] [92m      INFO[0m <class 'scalrpy.exceptions.AlreadyRunningError'> /opt/scalr-server/var/run/service/analytics_poller.pid
[30/Nov/2016 14:37:27][    analytics_poller][ 13462] [92m      INFO[0m <class 'scalrpy.exceptions.AlreadyRunningError'> /opt/scalr-server/var/run/service/analytics_poller.pid
[30/Nov/2016 14:37:30][    analytics_poller][ 13476] [92m      INFO[0m <class 'scalrpy.exceptions.AlreadyRunningError'> /opt/scalr-server/var/run/service/analytics_poller.pid

Comment: Well there ya go, your app expects to manage its own pidfile. Disable that, because supervisord handles all the process management.

Comment: I have seen that pid file, but there is a number (1149) inside it. There isn't much information inside that file. @coderanger

Comment: how to disable it. Can you be some more specific, please ?

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with using Supervisord to manage services, I would either read its documentation or hire someone more familiar with it to assist you.

Comment: I have no idea regarding supervisord, But suggest me how to disable that pidfile.